# c#: Wpf composition- how to block resize Button

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

Good day!

How to composite wpf window-

i have MenuItem, one big TextBox and one Button.

MenuItem shoud resize when user resize window, TextBox-the same thing, but Buttn should stay at place.

I try to do it, but button resezes or "go away" when user resize window:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="92*"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <MenuItem Header="Settings" Height="24">
            <MenuItem Header="Load" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,-10,0">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tBOutput"  TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

        </ScrollViewer>


    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="100" MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="200" Margin="5,10,-2,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="startBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Start!" Click="startBtn_Click" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="55" Width="90" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i clear recognize you, you can try something like this:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="92*"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <MenuItem Header="Settings" Height="24">
            <MenuItem Header="Load" />
            <MenuItem Header="Close" />
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,-10,0">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tBOutput"  TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

        </ScrollViewer>


    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,10,-2,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="startBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Start!" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="55" Width="90" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```